# NaN on video duration IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, video, nan

I want to create my own HTML5 Player with JS.

In Firefox everything works fine and shows the duration and the current time of the video on load.

But in IE the time on page load is NaN:NaN

whats wrong here ?

```
    $( video ).ready(function() {
                    var md = Math.floor(video.duration/60)<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(video.duration/60) : Math.floor(video.duration/60);
    var sd = Math.floor(video.duration-(md*60))<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(video.duration-(md*60)) : Math.floor(video.duration-(md*60));
    $('#remaining').html("00:00"+' / '+md+":"+sd);
video.volume = 0.3;

});
```

Comment: which version of IE are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868249/html5-audio-player-duration-showing-nan or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544243/html5-audio-duration-using-jquery or I am sure you can find plenty more.

Comment: I'm using IE 11 .. I don't want to know how much bad code it is in lower IE versions .. :D @epascarello this function doesn't work for me. It does nothing

Comment: so `$(video).on("loadedmetadata", function(){ console.log("here", video.duration ); });` does not fire for you?

Comment: correct. but somehow I think it's because it's in my function "window.onload = function() {...} could this be the problem?