# How to get HTML5 audio duration to show and avoid errors from play() and pause()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, html5-audio

I am having an issue getting the audio of an html5 audio object to load properly.  This is due to functions that are being run: `play()` and `pause()` and the duration is being returned before it is fully loaded.

Here is the code in the controller that calls a function to get the duration of the audio:

```
if (audioLoadButtonWasPressed) {
    $timeout(function () {
        scope.duration = audioFactory.retrieveDuration().toFixed(1);
    }, 200);
}
```

Here is retrieveDuration:

```
function retrieveDuration() {
  audio.play();
  audio.pause();
  if(audio.readyState != 0) {
      audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
  return audio.duration;
}
```

I have two issues with this code that have one root cause.  Because `play()` and `pause()` are running alongside each other, sometimes an error comes saying that `pause() prevented play() from running` then audio.duration is `NaN`. But everytime it runs, despite this, the function `getDuration()` always returns before it has a value causing `scope.duration` to always equal 0.0.

I have tried to add setTimeouts, promises, and other things to get the function to wait before returning, but it doesn't work and `toFixed()` is always undefined because there is no value returned from `retrieveDuration()`.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868249/html5-audio-player-duration-showing-nan) question on stackoverflow but I can't figure out how to get this event listener to work.  Any advice would help a bunch. Thank you!

Comment: Correct.  I placed the eventListener from that post inside of retrieveDuration, and the console.log didn't fire.

Comment: I don't think so.  Had the duration been loaded, this retrieveDuration would return a value, right?  Currently, it doesn't return a value. But if I put a breakpoint in retrieveDuration, it does return a value.  It's like I just need it to wait for a split second, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right.  What do you mean by "if .play() is blocking"?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/03hkfmq6/ works for me :P

Comment: Very nice. When I put this into retrieveDuration, it does do the alert, but it still shows zero. Do you know why? I thought it might have to do with where the play() and pause() were, but moving them around didn't change the result.

Comment: Hey you're good, thanks for the help.  Your fiddle works great.  But when I put the eventListener into my retrieveDuration function, it showed 'duration:0'. I just don't understand why it isn't working there.